# Session variable accessibility

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a class which creates a session the following way:

```
Session["UserId"] = UserId; // UserId = 1
```

In one of the pages on Page_Load, I retrieve the session variable value this way which works fine:

```
if (Session["UserId"] != null){

    var userid = Session["UserId"];
    Welcome.Text = "Hello, " + userid;

}
```

Now I need to use the value of the session variable in my classes as well. I used the following method to get the session value `int useridsession = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]);` but it always returns null whereas the session is correctly read using `Session["UserId"];` in my code behind file.

The mentioned class:

```
public static DataTable ManageBookingsDataTable()
{

    int useridsession = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Database.ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select bookings.id,user_id, start_date, end_date, pets.name AS 'Pet name' from bookings AS bookings left join users AS usr ON bookings.user_id=usr.id AND bookings.user_id=1 left join pets AS pets ON pets.id=bookings.pet_id WHERE bookings.user_id=@userid_session", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid_session", useridsession);

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string id = string.Empty;
    string name = string.Empty;
    string startdate = string.Empty;
    string enddate = string.Empty;
    string full_string = string.Empty;


    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            id = dt.Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
            var sdate = dt.Rows[i]["start_date"];
            name = dt.Rows[i]["Pet name"].ToString();
            startdate = dt.Rows[i]["start_date"].ToString();
            enddate = dt.Rows[i]["end_date"].ToString();
            full_string = startdate + " to " + enddate + " (" + name + ")";
            //CurrentBookings.Items.Add(new ListItem(full_string, id));
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

I diagnosed the problem by adding `HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] = 1;` which proves that when I set the session in the same class, the method works.

My question is how do I access the previously created session from any class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session should be available for the session regardless of the class. Why don't you set and get 
your session values using the same class? All your session stuff in a one place so it is more neat and tidy as well.

```
Local.MySession.UserId = UserId;  //Set here
int myUserId = Local.MySession.UserId; //Get here

//Something like this??
namespace Local
{
   //You can add all session variables to this class
   public class MySession
   {
      public static int UserId
      {
         get
         {
            return Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"] ?? "0");
         }
         set { HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"] = value.ToString(); }
      }

      public static string UserEmail //For Example another session variable
      {
         get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["email"] ?? ""; }
         set { HttpContext.Current.Session["email"] = value; }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Using getters and seterrs in a function to handle session from one place its neat solution indeed, that's how we learn. Thank you!